# Validating user input and carrying out the correct input

Tags: python

I am asking a user to type either 1 or 2, and if they don't enter a valid response, I prompt the input again. However, when I run this code, and there is an invalid input, it prompts them again, but if their new input is valid, it continues to prompt them again rather than carry out the code for the correct inputs.

```
userInputB = int(input("Enter '1' if you would like to get out of bed, or '2' if you would like to sleep in: "))
    while True:
        if userInputB == 1:
            print("Great! Let's move on.")
            break
        elif userInputB == 2:
            print("Okay. You have decided to sleep in for five more minutes.")
            for i in range(5,0,-1):
                print(i,'...')
            break
        while userInputB != 1 or userInputB != 2:
            print("Invalid Response.") 
            userInputB = int(input("Enter '1' if you would like to get out of bed, or '2' if you would like to sleep in: "))
```

Comment: You might like this syntax: `while userInputB not in [1, 2]:`

Answer (score 1):

this line is wrong:

```
while userInputB != 1 or userInputB != 2:
```

change to this (`AND`):

```
while userInputB != 1 and userInputB != 2:
```

and you code will be `fine`.